# Add a font awesome icon on the get_template_part / wordpress

Tags: wordpress

So, I have this code here:

```
<?php

do_action( 'tha_content_while_before' );

$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=19&posts_per_page=3' );

while ( $catquery->have_posts() ) : $catquery->the_post();

    get_template_part(
        'template-parts/content/content',
        apply_filters( 'wmhook_modern_loop_content_type', get_post_format())
    );


endwhile;

do_action( 'tha_content_while_after' );

?>
```

and I need to add a font awesome icon after the title that shows on the cards. But I'm not sure if is possible, I tried but nothing worked. if you know something let me know. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a file in a directory (template-parts/content/content.php), you need to open it and edit this file. There will be something like `the_title()`, just add your icon before it. If you need help, paste the contents of the file content.php here!